# Testing Branch.IO referral links on react native

Tags: react-native, branch.io

We use branch for referrals in our react native application. I have implemented branch successfully, now I want to test some scenarios.

When we click on a referral link, it navigates to app store or play store. But I want to do some debugging to identify if the params I pass are successfully send or not.

I have subscribed it like this. But how can I debug this with react-native debugger to see the console logs?

```
BranchIO.subscribe(async ({ error, params }) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error from Branch: ', error);
      return;
    }

    // Handle non-Branch URL.
    if (params['+non_branch_link']) return;

    // Indicates initialization success.
    // No link was opened.
    if (!params['+clicked_branch_link']) return;

    const installParams = await BranchIO.getFirstReferringParams();

    if (installParams?.$canonical_identifier === DeepLinkTypes.referral) {
      store.dispatch(setReferralKey(installParams.referralKey));
    }

    // A Branch link was opened.
    // Route link based on data in params
    navigatePath(params.$deeplink_path);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug if you are able to fetch the associated link data or not you can put in a debugger at the following line-

```
const installParams = await BranchIO.getFirstReferringParams();
```

Also we would suggest you to kindly use/update the above line to use `getLatestReferringParams`

```
let lastParams = await branch.getLatestReferringParams()
```

instead of getFirstReferringParams() since there are some recent issues reported lately with this method.
You can print out the parameters in the console and see for the link data.

Comment: Its working now. I sent an email to branch and they helped me to fix this. Thanks.